# What parameters should I use for the contains() method?

Tags: java

I don't really understand what parameters I should pass to the contains() method. I have my own class called Name which consists of 2 strings (firstName, secondName). I have created an ArrayList of type Name and 2 Name objects of the same name e.g. ("Joe, "Bloggs") 2x. So what paremeters do I have to pass to check whether it works. I have correctly overriden the equals method for Name class. This is my main program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EqualsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Name> names = new ArrayList<Name>();

        names.add(new Name("Joe", "Bloggs"));
        names.add(new Name("John", "Smith")); //<--
        names.add(new Name("Alan", "Wake"));  //   | the same name
        names.add(new Name("Robert", "High"));//   |
        names.add(new Name("John", "Smith")); //---

        names.contains(Name("Joe", "Bloggs"));      
    }
}
```

Comment: You correctly used the add method but you have problems with contains although they take the same parameters (one taking an object instead of the generic type of your List).

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you've overridden `equals` correctly in your `Name` class, it should be:

```
 if (names.contains(new Name("Joe", "Bloggs"))) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: thanks for that. my last question would be, why do I have to include "new" next to the name even when I call a method. I knew I have to do it while creating a new object in the array.

Comment: @Lazio You should be passing an instance of `Name` to the contains method, since the names list contains `Name` instances. You create a `Name` instance with a constructor call, which requires "new".

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
names.contains(new Name("Joe", "Bloggs"));
```

But you should override `equals()` method in Name class to work it as expected.

When ever you need to deal with collection frame work in `Java`, better to override both `equals()` and `hashCode()` method in your classes else you end up with mess.

Comment: its similar to other answer!!

Comment: @Prashant so? is that make difficulty to some one? I think you can see some other points in my answer.

Comment: if you are giving some different approach then its fine otherwise simply vote-up the previous answer!! that what i mean .

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera, your answer helped me as well. It's kind of different to the other one.